# OSX Fullscreen (Kiosk) Application <Error:> Invalid Context 0x0

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an OS X application that I would like to run in fullscreen. My search has led me to two solutions:

1. the `collectionBehavior` property of `NSWindow`, and
2. the `- enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:` function of `NSView`.

My application goes to fullscreen with either of those methods, but when using `NSWindow`'s `collectionBehavior` set to `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary` and toggling it using `- toggleFullScreen:nil` I get a whole lot of errors in my output:

```
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
      <-[NSFrameView drawWindowBackgroundRect:]+48>
       <-[NSThemeFrame drawWindowBackgroundRect:]+129>
        <-[NSFrameView drawThemeContentFill:inView:]+290>
         <-[NSFrameView drawRect:]+1156>
          <-[NSThemeFrame drawRect:]+280>
           <-[NSView _drawRect:clip:]+3626>
            <-[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:]+1873>
             <-[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]+838>
              <-[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]+334>
               <-[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:]+2449>
                <-[NSView displayIfNeeded]+1950>
                 <-[NSWindow displayIfNeeded]+232>
                  <___NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserver_block_invoke6367+476>
                   <__37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke+738>
                    <_ZN2CA11Transaction19run_commit_handlersE18CATransactionPhase+85>
                     <_ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE+160>
                      <_ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv+508>
                       <_ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv+71>
                        <__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__+23>
                         <__CFRunLoopDoObservers+391>
                          <__CFRunLoopRun+1178>
                           <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+296>
                            <RunCurrentEventLoopInMode+235>
                             <ReceiveNextEventCommon+432>
                              <_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter+71>
                               <_DPSNextEvent+1067>
                                <-[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]+454>
                                 <-[NSApplication run]+682>
                                  <F***REDACTED***_main+206>
                                   <_ZN7***REDACTED***RunAppEiPPcPNS_11ApplicationE+745>
                                    <main+104>
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
      <__40-[NSAppearance _setCustomColor:setType:]_block_invoke+72>
       <-[NSCompositeAppearance _callCoreUIWithBlock:]+183>
        <-[NSAppearance _setCustomColor:setType:]+138>
         <-[NSDynamicSystemColor set]+60>
          <NSDrawWindowBackground+175>
           <-[NSFrameView drawWindowBackgroundRect:]+48>
            <-[NSThemeFrame drawWindowBackgroundRect:]+129>
            [OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextGetAllowsDithering: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetAllowsDithering: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetAllowsDithering: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
Feb  2 14:37:02  ***REDACTED***[10137] <Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace: [CALLSTACK OMITTED FOR BREVITY]
```

I tried putting a symbolic breakpoint on `CGPostError`, but I wasn't able to glean anything useful from the disassembly.

Most online references to `invalid context 0x0` are from iOS, not OSX, where the solution was either a bug in iOS or a missing `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` entry in the app's `Info.plist`, which is not helpful in my case.

I tried disabling the menu bar and the dock with `NSApplicationPresentationOptions`, but that didn't change anything.

If I use `- enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:` on the `NSView` instead, there are no errors, but I prefer to keep the default fullscreen switch animation I get when using `- toggleFullScreen:`.

Switching to `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary` makes the errors go away, which leads me to believe the problem might have something to do with the "blackout" rectangle that gets automatically drawn behind my app. (I remember reading something about that somewhere.)

What is trying to draw into an invalid context and how can I give it a valid context?

The relevant app initialization from my `NSResponder <NSApplicationDelegate>`:

```
// Create the window
self.Window = [NSWindow alloc];
[self.Window initWithContentRect:bounds
                       styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                         backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                           defer:YES];

// Create the view
self.View = [NSView alloc];
[self.View initWithFrame:bounds];
[self.View setWantsLayer:YES];    // The generated layer is CAMetalLayer

// Associate the view with the window
[self.Window setContentView:self.View];

// Misc
[self.Window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self.Window];
[self.Window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
[self.Window setHidesOnDeactivate:YES];

// Fullscreen
[self.Window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
[self.Window toggleFullScreen:nil];
[self.Window makeFirstResponder:self.View];
```

Thanks.